# Проверка файла на наличие определенных строк во время сборки

Tags: java, maven

Требуется проверять файл xml на наличие определенных значений свойства.
Думал сделать через antrun plugin и shell скрипт. Возможно существует способ лучше?

Answer (score 0):

первое, что пришло в голову - это два варианта))

1. вариант посложнее - взять за основу плагин мавена (если сборка мавеном) и поковырять его, переписать под себя (делали так в одном из проектов, но очень давно)
2. вариант попроще и логичнее - просто в проект добавить тесты, которые будут проверять нужные файлы (xml, в Вашем случае)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LScps3Dl7Vw
смотреть с 1:01:30 будет рассказ как валить билд или информировать при сборке о наличии ключевых слов в сорцах
лучше посмотреть все, очень интересно